# Calculate max mean from dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
dict = {'A' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[5,2,5,6,1,1], 'C':[0,34,5,6]}
```

And I want to calculate which key has the biggest mean

output:

```
>>> 'C'   because     (11.25) > 6.666 > 5
```

I have tried something like this:

```
import statistics
    max(max(mean(dict())), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: posted  lol sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is not really valid code. You are passing dict(), which is Python's built-in function, as an argument to mean, which takes an iterable as argument. Try this:

```
from statistics import mean
ans = list(dct.keys())[0]
# ans is the first key of the dictionary
max_mean = mean(dct[ans])
# initialize max_mean as the mean of the first list
for k, v in dct.items():
    if(mean(v) > max_mean):
        ans = k
        max_mean = mean(v)
```

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question. I don't want the mean as the result, I want the key .

Comment: @LokoLokoNini I have altered my answer to suit your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use of `max` with a key function.

```
>>> max(dict, key=lambda k: statistics.mean(dict[k]))
'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a list with all of the means, get the index of the maximum mean and return the key by index:

```
dict = {'A' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[5,2,5,6,1,1], 'C':[0,34,5,6]}

list_with_means = list()
for key in dict.keys():
    list_with_means.append(sum(dict.get(key)) / len(dict.get(key)))

list(dict)[list_with_means.index(max(list_with_means))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from statistics import mean
dict = {'A' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[5,2,5,6,1,1], 'C':[0,34,5,6]}

#make a dictionary comprehension that gets the means of the vals
meanDict = { k:mean(v) for (k,v) in zip(dict.keys(), dict.values())}
print(meanDict)
#{'A': 3, 'B': 3.3333333333333335, 'C': 11.25}

#find the key with the highest val
keyMax = max(meanDict, key=meanDict.get)
print(keyMax)
#C

#print key and value that have the highest mean
print(keyMax, meanDict.get(keyMax))
#C 11.25
```